# How to archive old revisions from Apache SVN on linux server

Tags: linux, apache, svn, version-control, revision-history

I have a site through which user can write their own Screenplays.

This screenplays are saved in the form of revisions.

Apache SVN has been installed.

I want to save only the last 5 revisions for every user's document.

But the problem is on the backend the all the revisions are stored in one folder called "Docsrepo" and its classified as 1000 revisions in 1 folder. and like this it has 234 folders.

Meaning 234*1000 revisions.

Now I want to archive all of this revision to keep only the last 5 revisions of each document.

How do i do that?

Comment: SVN doesn't store complete copies of every single revision, it only stores differences.  So I'm not sure what you're describing.

Comment: Also, the '1000' you're seeing is not the actual number of revisions in that folder.  SVN "shards" revisions in the file system, which is an easy way for SVN to know that when it has to deal with revision number 687, it should look in the '1000' folder; revision number 3465, it should look in the '3000' folder; and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to add a hook to SVN so that when a user checks in a new revision you can ditch the oldest revision. However, you do realize that SVN isn't keeping 1000*234 complete copies of each script right? SVN only saves the difference between each version.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the folders you'll see each revision is stored as a separate file, so you can see the sizes. Each of those files are really storing the deltas, or differences, between the checkins so they should be really small.

With later versions of SVN, you can run the 'svnadmin pack' command which combines all the files in 1 folder into a single bigger file. This helps performance as the OS will be better able to cache the single file, however, it only works on older folders that are full - ie ones that will not get additions to them. Its safe to run though, and you can run it as often as you like (some people run it on each checkin, some people run it weekly or monthly).

Now, you can not just delete the old files as you've already seen each file contains just the differences between it and the previous revision, so if you deleted the old file, SVN wouldn't be able to re-create the total file based on all the changes over time.

There is a slight complication to this. SVN uses a thing called [skip-deltas](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/skip-deltas), which are 'checkpoints' where it stores a roll-up of all previous differences which means you get much better performance. However, this still doesn't mean you can just delete old files unless you know you can re-create each file (and I guess you won't know how many actual checkins have occurred for each file).

---

So.. to get to answer your question:

you can dump and load your repository, ignoring ancient files. This involves the svnadmin dump and svnadmin load commands. [You dump the repo into a dumpfile](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnadmin) using only the last 5 revision numbers and then load the dumpfile into a new repo. (I think there's also options for dumping based on date).

Note you cannot keep the last 5 revisions of each file. You can only dump a range of revisions.

Obviously this is a manual, admin task and is usually used for removing ancient revisions no-one will ever see again. There is no automatic 'only keep the last 5 revisions' option.
The need for removing revisions is minor however, SVN is very good at keeping performance fast, and the deltas are small, so there should be no need to remove the history. If you are really running short of disk space, then the dump/load option is your best bet.